Change page with tabset change
I have a html rmarkdown in R. I want each sub section to appear alone in a page and be in the same space when I scroll down. I.e I want each chunk to appear on its own.
Is that possible? And if yes what modifications I have to make to appear this way ?
Below is my code:
---
title: "test tabsets"
output:
  html_document: 
    theme: simplex
    highlight: null
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
date: "2024-04-20"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
pagebreak <- function() {
  if(knitr::is_latex_output())
    return("\\newpage")
  else
    return('<div style="page-break-before: always;" />')
}
```


```{r, echo=FALSE , include=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(kableExtra))
```

# Sections {.tabset .tabset-fade}
`r pagebreak()`
### summary cars
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
`r pagebreak()`
### Including Plots

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
`r pagebreak()`
### structure

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```


I don't really understand. What do you mean with "each chunk to appear on its own"? Do you have an example link to a page or a picture which shows the desired result?

@Jan I mean if I click on tab including plots I want to see only this plot not the previous summary cars and part of the structure (next tab).
Now imagine instead of clicking on each tab to scroll down.Each tab must be a different page.Like turning a page of a book.

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements, but here is a script you could drop in your RMarkdown that may work for you. For any sections you want to make "zoomable", add a {.zoomable} behind the header.
$( window ).on("load", function() {
    $( ".tocify-item" ).on("click", function() {
        var toc_element = $( this );
        var duv = toc_element.attr("data-unique");
        
        var content_element = $( 'div[data-unique="' + duv + '"]' ).parent();
        
        if(content_element.parent().hasClass("zoomable")) {
            $( "#header" ).hide();
            $( ".section" ).hide();
            content_element.parent().show();
            content_element.show();
        } else {
            $( "#header" ).show();
            $( ".section" ).show();
        };
    });
});

Use it like so:
---
title: "Zoomable Sections"
output:
  html_document: 
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
date: "2024-04-20"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{js, echo=FALSE}
$( window ).on("load", function() {
    $( ".tocify-item" ).on("click", function() {
        var toc_element = $( this );
        var duv = toc_element.attr("data-unique");
        
        var content_element = $( 'div[data-unique="' + duv + '"]' ).parent();
        
        if(content_element.parent().hasClass("zoomable")) {
            $( "#header" ).hide();
            $( ".section" ).hide();
            content_element.parent().show();
            content_element.show();
        } else {
            $( "#header" ).show();
            $( ".section" ).show();
        };
    });
});
```

# Header 1

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`

# Zoomable Sections {.zoomable}

## Summary Cars 

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

## Structure

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```

# Header 2

`r stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(1)`

